# Javascript equivalent of Kalileo's Visualizer?

Tags: javascript, networking, visualization

Hye

I want to migrate from flash to javascript to visualize my data. My data is a concept map with semantic relationships. In flash I was using "Kalileo's Visualizer" to do something like this 
http://lab.kapit.fr/skin/frontend/default/kaplab/images/kap-lab-kalileo-3.png.
Kalieleo allows me to

- Add/remove nodes/links (dynamically and statically)
- Add nodes    without parents
- Group nodes
- Re-layout of the visualization in    case of dynamic
  addition/subtraction of nodes/links
- Drag/drop nodes

I've looked into many existing js frameworks including InfoVis JIT, Dracula, D3.js, Sigma.js, etc. The closest I got is the "Force-Directed Graph" but I want a visualization in a hiearchical layout.

Could someone show me another javascript/(html5) library that can do what I want?

Regards